# how to only change floats that are whole numbers like 25.0, into integer and keep floats like 25.9 as floats in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My goal is to only convert not whole numbers into fractions(like 0.5 into 1/2) and change numbers like 25.0 into integers. I know to how to convert decimals into fractions but my code will change 25.0 into 25/1 instead just printing 25. I've tried using isinstance(25.0, int) to check but it only returns false.
Any suggestion on how to help my code distinguish between the two. I'm using python 3.9

Comment: `1.5` is not `1/2`.

Comment: Check whether the denominator is 1?

Comment: If your code changes `25.0` into `25/1` - can't you add a check to see if the denominator is `1`, and if it is, cast it as `int` instead? Python also have a `fractions` module that may help further: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

Comment: Try `number % 1`, will be `False` for `.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Python floats have handy `as_integer_ratio()` and `is_integer()` methods. So you can use either of:

```
def float2int_maybe_1(f):
    return int(f) if f.is_integer() else f
```

or

```
def float2int_maybe_2(f):
    n, d = f.as_integer_ratio()
    return n if d == 1 else f
```

If you're interested with fractional representation, you can probably use the information from `as_integer_ratio` for your other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own function. Here’s one simple `lambda function`.

```
divide = lambda i,j: i//i if i/j  == i //j else i/j
```

Now if you do:

```
divide(25,1) # 1
divide(25,2) # 12.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) built-in module, following way:

```
import fractions
def f(x):
    frac = fractions.Fraction(x)
    return int(frac) if frac.denominator == 1 else frac
print(f(25.0))
print(f(1.5))
```

output

```
25
3/2
```